# Ionic 5 ion refresh problem when we also used ion gesture

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic5, ion-list

I used ionic 5 as a framework.
In one of my page i used ion-refresher with ion-gesture functionality.Now in that page when i used that without ion-refresh i can swipe my ion-item which is inside ion-content.But when i used ion-refresh it is not swipable

> customer-in-app-notification.html

```
    <ion-content>
  <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
  <ng-container *ngIf="notifications.length>0">
    <ion-list *ngFor="let list of notifications" swipeAll (swiperight)="removeNotification($event,list)">
      ...
    </ion-list>
  </ng-container>
</ion-content>
```

When i swiperight it move my ion-item using custom created gesure

> tsfile

```
  swiperight() {
console.log('HEloo');
const listn = this.list.toArray();
for (const i of listn) {
  console.log(i);
  const gesture: Gesture = this.gestureCtrl.create(
    {
      el: i.nativeElement,
      gestureName: 'swipe right',
      onMove: (ev) => {
        console.log(ev);
        i.nativeElement.style.transform = `translateX(${ev.deltaX}px)`;
      },
      onEnd: (ev) => {
        if (ev.deltaX > 200 && ev.deltaX < 1000 && ev.velocityX > 0.1) {
          i.nativeElement.style.transition = '.2s ease-out';
          i.nativeElement.style.transform = `translateX(1000px)`;
        } else {
          i.nativeElement.style.transform = '';
        }
      }
    }, true);
  gesture.enable(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Just a guess, but it might work if you increase the priority of the gesture to be higher than `ion-refresher` ([which is 31](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/core/src/components/refresher/refresher.tsx#L245))

Comment: Can you also tell me what is the priority of ion-Refresher?@Thomas

Comment: Thank you for help @Thomas.I try with set priority in gesture like
const gesture: Gesture = this.gestureCtrl.create(
        {
          el: i.nativeElement,
          gestureName: 'swipe right',
          gesturePriority: 30,..
}
And it worked.Thank you for help